# Typescript Function Weird Void || && Behaviour

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why is `returnObject`causing an compilation TypeError `returnObject2` isn't?

Normally, `void || something` should return `something` while `void && something` should return `void`.

But in Typescript, it's the opposite that occurs.

```
var returnVoid = function(){};

var returnObject = function(){  //Typescript compilation TypeError. 
    //No best common type exists among return expressions.
    if(Math.random() < 0.5)
        return new Error();
    return returnVoid() || null; //always return null
}
var returnObject2 = function(){ //works
    if(Math.random() < 0.5)
        return new Error();
    return returnVoid() && null; //always return undefined
}
```

Note: TypeError occurs during the compilation, not in the runtime.

---

EDIT: I did another test. Shouldn't `returnNum2` be `() => number` too considering `(undefined || something) === something`? Note: Same behaviour for `void 0`.

```
var returnNum = function(){ //() => number
    return undefined || 0; 
}

var returnVoid = function(){};

var returnNum2 = function(){ //() => void | number
    return returnVoid() || 0; 
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean... `undefined` is the same than `void` which is a "false" value in `||` and `&&` operations.

Comment: I don't understand how the posted code demonstrates anything. How are those functions called?  The first will return either an error or `null`, while the second returns either an error or `undefined`.

Comment: TypeScript appears to operate as you said in your "Normally, ..." sentence (per https://jsfiddle.net/v8hc73n9/1/). What's the exact problem?

Comment: The opposite would be that it returns `undefined` and not `something`, yet it returns a Type Error, so it's not the opposite.

Comment: Yes, I added it. `No best common type exists among return expressions.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been pointed out in comments, but I think in general you just need to understand that `function(){}` will return `undefined`, which has specified behavior for logical operators.

For `undefined && somevalue`, undefined will always be returned. For `undefined || somevalue`, somevalue will be evaluated and returned.

Here's a good reference for more information: http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/comparison_operators.shtml

EDIT: The question isn't about what is returned for the logical operation, but why typescript gives `error TS2354: No best common type exists among return expressions.` on compilation.

This does seem like an error, but may make sense in the context. If you replace the logical operators with just a call to `returnVoid()` only, you'll get the same error in both functions. Static typing allows the `&&` operator to short-circuit entirely for typing, since `something && null` will never evaluate to a type, but `something || null` could depending on what the `something` is.

Related to this, in typescript you cannot explicitly specify null or undefined as a return type for a function.

While I understand why this may be the case, I agree it is a little odd. It might be worth checking with the folks who make Typescript and filing a bug.

Comment: Yes, according to that logic, the Typescript TypeError should occur in `returnObject2`, not in `returnObject`.

Comment: @RainingChain I see, I missed the base of the question. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript doesn't special case expressions of the form `undefined || T` or `void || T` to be `T` because a) you shouldn't write that code (use the comma operator!) and b) it's not safe to write this code because return value contravariance means you're not guaranteed to have a falsy value just because you have a void-returning function reference.

Consider if you wrote code like this:

```
type callback = (arg: any) => void;

function doSomething(x: callback) {
    return x(10) || 'Hello, world!';
}

var x = [];
var add = (arg: any) => x.push(arg);
console.log(doSomething(add)); // Prints '1', not 'Hello, world!'
```